# How can you get a unique ID for a rendering on a specific Sitecore item?

Tags: presentation

I need to programmatically update all of the instances of a particular rendering attached to a Sitecore item.

This is the code I first tried and failed to use:

```cs
foreach (RenderingReference renderingReference in parentRenderingReferences)
{
    /* ... unrelated code removed ... */
    var layoutField = new LayoutField(contentItem.Fields[FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
    LayoutDefinition layoutDef = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
    DeviceDefinition deviceDef = layoutDef.GetDevice(device.ID.ToString());

    // Update the rendering's datasource
    RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition =
        deviceDef.GetRendering(renderingReference.RenderingID);
    renderingDefinition.Datasource = newDataSourceValue;
    /* ... unrelated code removed ... */
}
```

Using `RenderingReference.RenderingID` in the final statement in that code didn't work, as the `RenderingID` is the ID of the actual rendering item that lives in /layouts/renderings. So if the item has more than one of the same rendering on a template the code never accesses any renderings after the first instance. I tried using `RenderingReference.UniqueID`, which appeared to be what I was looking for  (the ID of the instance of the rendering):

```cs
foreach (RenderingReference renderingReference in parentRenderingReferences)
{
    /* ... unrelated code removed ... */
    var layoutField = new LayoutField(contentItem.Fields[FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
    LayoutDefinition layoutDef = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
    DeviceDefinition deviceDef = layoutDef.GetDevice(device.ID.ToString());

    // Update the rendering's datasource
    RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition =
        deviceDef.GetRendering(renderingReference.UniqueID);
    renderingDefinition.Datasource = newDataSourceValue;
    /* ... unrelated code removed ... */
}
```

In this case, the resulting `renderingDefinition` object is null, so that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 8):

The solution that ended up working for me was to use the `DeviceDefinition.GetRenderingByUniqueId` method with the `RenderingReference.UniqueID` object:

```cs
foreach (RenderingReference renderingReference in parentRenderingReferences)
{
    /* ... unrelated code removed ... */
    var layoutField = new LayoutField(contentItem.Fields[FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
    LayoutDefinition layoutDef = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
    DeviceDefinition deviceDef = layoutDef.GetDevice(device.ID.ToString());

    // Update the rendering's datasource
    RenderingDefinition renderingDefinition =
        deviceDef.GetRenderingByUniqueId(renderingReference.UniqueID);
    renderingDefinition.Datasource = newDataSourceValue;
    /* ... unrelated code removed ... */
}
```

Comment: I posted this question and answer together because I spent way too long trying to figure this out myself, and when my team helped me, I didn't want that information to get lost. But please, if you have a better solution, I want to hear it!

Comment: I would use `LayoutField(item)` instead of `new LayoutField(contentItem.Fields[FieldIDs.LayoutField])` because from Sitecore 8.0 we have `Shared Renderings` and `Final Renderings`. Here is the related documentation - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/creating_and_editing_items/versioning/the_versioned_layout_api_changes